# Android SurfaceView show image after video (clear surface)

Tags: android, image, video, surfaceview

My task - play video on SurfaceView, after stop show image in SurfaceView

My code for play

```java
mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
mPlayer.setDisplay(view.getHolder());
mPlayer.reset();
mPlayer.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
mPlayer.prepare();
mPlayer.start();
```

all ok video playing

in onCompletion

```java
mPlayer.reset();
mPlayer.setDisplay(null);
view.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(file.toString()));
```

but image is transparend and on background i see last video frame - its no good. How clear surface?

I try use

```java
holder.lockCanvas()
```

but this return null, why?

Answer (score 3):

I have a same problem and i fixed it by using these two lines after player release.

```
surfaceViewHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
surfaceViewHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.OPAQUE);
```